# nose framework command line regex pattern matching doesnt work(-e,-m ,-i)

Tags: python, regex, testing, automated-tests, nose

The python nosetest framework has some command line options to include, exclude and match regex for tests which can be included/excluded and matched respectively.

However they don't seem to be working correctly.

```
[kiran@my_redhat test]$ nosetests -w cases/ -s -v  -m='_size'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s
OK
[kiran@my_redhat test]$ grep '_size' cases/test_case_4.py
    def test_fn_size_sha(self):
```

is there some thing wrong with regex matching semantics of nose framework?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nosetests' -m argument is used to match directories, **filenames**, classes, and functions.  ([See the nose docs explanation of this parameter](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#cmdoption-m))  In your case, the filename of your test file (test_case_4.py) does not match the -m match expression (_size), so is never opened.

You may notice that if you force nose to open your test file, it *will* run only the specified test:

```
nosetests -sv -m='_size' cases/test_case_4.py
```

In general, when I want to match specific tests or subsets of tests I use the [--attrib plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html), which is available in the default nose install. You may also want to try excluding tests that match some pattern.

Comment: Hi @dbw, Thankyou for replying. However i tried this and this is what i found
    
`[k@e test]$ grep '_size' cases/test_case_04_inv_validation.py
        def test_fn_size_sha(self):
 [k@e test]$ nosetests -sv -m='_size' cases/test_case_04_inv_validation.py

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK`

Comment: Is test_fn_size_sha() in a TestCase class? If so, that class is subject to the same match rules, so it will be rejected if it doesn't match the -m expression.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing '=' when specifying the regexp:

```
$ nosetests -w cases/ -s -v -m '_size'
```

or keep '=' and spell out --match:

```
$ nosetests -w cases/ -s -v --match='_size'
```

Answer (score 1):

Nose is likely using Python's `re.match`, or something equivalent, which requires a match at the beginning of the string. `_size` doesn't match because the function name `test_fn_size_sha` doesn't start with the regex `_size`.

Try using a regex that matches from the beginning:

```
nosetests -w cases/ -s -v -m='\w+_size'
```

Comment: hmmm.. thats a good thought @voithos. however


[kiran@my_redhat test]$ nosetests -w cases/ -s -v -m='\w+_size'

Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK
[kiran@my_redhat test]$ nosetests -w cases/ -s -v -m='_size'

Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK
[kiran@my_redhat test]$ grep _size cases/test_case_size.py
    def _size_sha(self):
`

Comment: @KiranBangalore: What about `.*_size`?

Comment: no luck...
[kiran@my_redhat test]$ nosetests -w cases/ -s -v -m='.*_size'

Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

Comment: @KiranBangalore: Is your `cases` directory a Python package? (does it contain a `__init__.py` file?)

Comment: and this is a little shocking for me...
[kiran@my_redhat test]$ nosetests -w cases/ -s -v -m='test_fn_size_sha'

Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK

Comment: @KiranBangalore: You need one. Your tests directory needs to be importable - make an empty `__init__.py`.

Comment: just added  the file . still no luck

Comment: @KiranBangalore: What happens when you remove the `-m` flag?

Comment: the default match criterian kicks in...  `Default: (?:^|[\b_\./-])[Tt]est`

Comment: @KiranBangalore: And is it able to find the tests?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34865/discussion-between-kiran-bangalore-and-voithos)

Comment: This is not a correct explanation of the problem.  See my answer about what nose matches with the match expression.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me .

```
nosetests --collect-only test_mytest\test_category --exclude=test_.*Pin
```

Here I have excluded all test that has a word "Pin" in the test case name.

Note: All test case names start with test_ in my case.