# nosetests regex matching (-m) doesn't work with classes

Tags: python, nose

I try to run the following

```
nosetests my_test_file.py --match "Test.+"
```

The name of my test classes all start with "Test". I tried a lot of other regexes, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select some test methods in a fixture using regex (i.e. -m) in nosetests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992608/how-to-select-some-test-methods-in-a-fixture-using-regex-i-e-m-in-nosetests)

Comment: Thanks, looks like a duplicate.